# React ref to functional component without hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find out if an element is currently visible. The problem is I need a ref to that component,but it's a functional component, so I get the error `Function components cannot be given refs`

```
class ShowPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      sorting:'desc',
      lastPostDate:'none',
      hasMore:false,
      pageNumber:0
    };
    this.lastPostRef = React.createRef();
  }
 render(){
  //Irelevant code above
       postList = posts.map((post, k) =>
      {
        if(k===posts.length-1)
          return <PostCard ref={this.lastPostRef} post={post} key={k} />
        return <PostCard post={post} key={k} />
      }
}
...
```

**Edit:**
I'm trying to find out if I reached that element by scrolling (trying to implement pagination). So I'll use it in the my scroll listener

```
  onScroll()
  {
    console.log(`Last post is ${this.lastPost}`);
    if(this.lastPostRef)
    {
      var rect = this.lastPostRef.getBoundingClientRect();
      var elemTop = rect.top;
      var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
      console.log(elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0);//Check if element is visible
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you want to use the ref for? Can you show where else `lastPostRef` is being used?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use forwardRef to pass the ref inside the functional component. Check the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

```
const PostCard = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  ...
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just attach the ref to the DOM element rendered inside `PostCard`, it looks like it should give you what you're expecting. Instead of

```
return <PostCard ref={this.lastPostRef} post={post} key={k} />
```

you can use

```
return <PostCard theRef={this.lastPostRef} post={post} key={k} />
```

(bypassing the limitation on the `ref` prop name), and then, inside `postCard`, do something along the lines of:

```
const PostCard = ({ theRef, post }) => {
  // ...
  return (
    <div ref={theRef}>
```

so that the PostCard takes the ref as a prop and passes it down as a prop to the element that gets rendered.

If you wanted, you could also use the conditional operator instead of an `if` to make things a bit less repetitive. In `showPosts`:

```
{
  <PostCard
    ref={k === posts.length - 1 ? this.lastPostRef : null}
    post={post}
    key={k}
  />
}
```